# vuejs list rendering attribute = index?

Tags: arrays, list, vue.js, vue-component, rendering

i'm trying to render a list of studends

```
  <div v-for="(item , index) in students" nrow='index' :key="item.name" class="row textsh">
                    <div class="presente-assente nascosto">
                      <label onclick="confirm(this,'ssj1')" class="textsh prvb" for=""><i class="fas fa-check"></i></label>
                      <label onclick="confirm(this,'ssj2')" class="textsh assvb" for=""><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
                    </div>
                    <span  class="numbstudent">{{index+1}}</span>
                    <span onclick="sel_row(this)" class="namestudent">{{item.name}}</span>      
                  </div>
```

is there a way to say that the attribute "nrow" should be the current index in the for?

Answer (score 1):

what about moving the v-for one level higher, like this:

```
<div v-for="(item , index) in students">
  <div  nrow='index' :key="item.name" class="row textsh">
  <div class="presente-assente nascosto">
    <label onclick="confirm(this,'ssj1')" class="textsh prvb" for=""><i class="fas fa-check"></i></label>
    <label onclick="confirm(this,'ssj2')" class="textsh assvb" for=""><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
  </div>
  <span  class="numbstudent">{{index+1}}</span>
  <span onclick="sel_row(this)" class="namestudent">{{item.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```